# Type cast a field created on-the-fly using AS "new_field" in a SELECT subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, subquery, column-alias

## Context

I have a really *tiny* issue while creating a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) table using a `SELECT` sub-query where I'd like to initialize a field with `NULL` values of type `INTEGER` (they default to `TEXT` if I do not specify the type).

Enough talking, here is the piece of code with the background explanations:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS
  SELECT
    0 AS fid, -- initiate new field here, it doesn't exist in the table where the select is run on
    gid,
    min(distance) AS mindist
  FROM
    schema.points
  GROUP BY
    gid;
```

This is working as expected, I've got `0` everywhere in the `fid` field that I need to create at this time.

But I'm not quite happy with `0` values because they will have a significant meaning in further computations, hence I'd like to initialize this `fid` field with `NULL` values (don't worry, it's not a `pkey`).

Therefore, I've changed it to this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS
  SELECT
    NULL AS fid, -- initiate new field here, it doesn't exist in the table where the select is run on
    gid,
    min(distance) AS mindist
  FROM
    schema.points
  GROUP BY
    gid;
```

And it's working well!
Except that now the field is a `TEXT` field (it looks like it's the "default" type when `NULL` is used), and I really need it as an `INTEGER` (I'm running into further trouble if I let it as `TEXT`).

## Question

How could I set (i.e. cast, technically speaking) the `fid` field to `NULL` **and** of type `INTEGER` at the same time in this particular query?

None of these works (I'm facing syntax errors each time):

- `NULL AS fid::INTEGER`
- `INTEGER NULL AS fid`
- `NULL INTEGER AS fid`

### Environment

PostgreSQL 10.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have to set the type cast after null, using:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS
  SELECT
    NULL::INTEGER AS fid, -- initiate new field here as a NULL INTEGER
    gid,
    min(distance) AS mindist
  FROM
    schema.points
  GROUP BY
    gid;
```

Then you will have it:

[image: pgAdmin results]

Results in [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/).